# How can I draw a line along my graph to show me where the data density is the highest?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot, graphics

```
datos = fits.open('/home/citlali/Documentos/Servicio/Lista.fits')
data = datos[1].data


#Linea [SIII] 9532
Mask_1 = data['flux_[SIII]9531.1_Re_fit'] / data['e_flux_[SIII]9531.1_Re_fit'] > 5
newdata1 = data[Mask_1]
dat_flux = newdata1['flux_[SIII]9069.0_Re_fit']
dat_eflux = newdata1['e_flux_[SIII]9069.0_Re_fit']
Mask_2 = dat_flux / dat_eflux > 5
newdata2 = newdata1[Mask_2]


H1_alpha = newdata1['log_NII_Ha_Re']
H1_beta = newdata1['log_OIII_Hb_Re']
H2_alpha = newdata2['log_NII_Ha_Re']
H2_beta = newdata2['log_OIII_Hb_Re']


M = H1_alpha < -0.9
newx = H1_alpha[M]
newy = H1_beta[M]  
ex = newx 
ey = newy 
#print("Elementos de SIII [9532]: ", len(newx))
m = H2_alpha < -0.9
newxm = H2_alpha[m]
newym = H2_beta[m] 
#print("Elementos de SIII [9069]: ", len(newxm))

sm = heapq.nsmallest(3000, zip(newx, newy)) # zip them to sort together
newx, newy = zip(*sm) # unzip them

plt.figure()
plt.plot(H1_alpha, H1_beta, '*', color ='darkred', markersize="7", label = "SIII [9532]") 
plt.plot(H2_alpha, H2_beta, '.', color ='rosybrown', markersize="3", label = "SIII [9069]")
plt.xlim(-1.5, 0.75)
plt.ylim(-1, 1) 
plt.title('Diagrama de diagnóstico')
plt.ylabel('OIII/Hbeta')
plt.xlabel('NII/Halpha')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(8, 6)
plt.show()
```

[image: coding plot]
In the figure I show my plot, and the black line is what I want to obtain.

The code reads me downloaded data that I have plotted, it shows galaxies with a signal/noise greater than 5. The data to consider for plotting the line must be H1_alpha, H1_beta and/or H2_alpha, H2_beta.

Comment: Are you asking how to perform curve fitting?

Comment: @jared yes, but considering the density of points (that the curve passes where there is the highest concentration of them along the graph).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example below using a test dataset shows how you can derive sample weights based on density, and then supply those sample weights to a curve fitting algorithm.

The example dataset is a quadratic-like curve/density embedded in noise:

[image]

We can model the density using sklearn's `GaussianMixture`. It provides a score for each sample, where higher scores correspond to the more probable (i.e more dense) areas.

[image]

Using scipy's `curve_fit()` to fit a quadratic curve using the previously-computed sample weights (scipy interprets them as error bars, so use `1/sample_weights`):

[image]

Alternatively, using sklearn's SVR which takes the sample weights directly (though results are nearly identical):

[image]

Overlaying the individual steps:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Make some test data - a quadratic curve embedded in noise
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
X1, y1 = make_moons(500, noise=0.7, random_state=0)
X2, y2 = make_moons(500, noise=0.4, random_state=1)
X3, y3 = make_moons(600, noise=0.08, random_state=2)
X = np.concatenate([X1, X2, X3[y3==0]], axis=0)

#View the data
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], marker='.', s=10)
plt.gca().set(xlabel='x0', ylabel='x1')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(5, 3)

#Model the density
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
gmm = GaussianMixture(n_components=20, random_state=0).fit(X)

xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-2, 3), np.linspace(-3, 3))
log_scores = gmm.score_samples(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()]).reshape(xx.shape)
scores = np.exp(log_scores)

plt.contour(xx, yy, scores, levels=8, cmap='plasma_r', alpha=1)

#Get the density score for each datapoint
data_scores = np.exp(gmm.score_samples(X))
# can scale scores to max value = 1
data_scores /= data_scores.max()

#Fit quadratic curve using scipy's curve_fit
# supply 1/data_scores as the sample errors
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

#Fit a quadratic curve
(A, B, C), _ = curve_fit(lambda x, A, B, C: A*x**2 + B*x + C, X[:, 0], X[:, 1], sigma=1 / data_scores)

x_axis = X[:, 0][np.argsort(X[:, 0])].reshape(-1, 1)

plt.plot(
    x_axis,
    A * x_axis**2 + B * x_axis + C,
    color='tab:brown', lw=10, alpha=0.3, label='curve_fit()'
)
plt.gcf().legend()

#Alternatively, using support vector regressor from sklearn
# Takes data_scores directly as relative sample weights
from sklearn.svm import SVR

#Quadratic curve, as before
svr = SVR(kernel='poly', degree=2).fit(X[:, [0]], X[:, 1], sample_weight=data_scores)
plt.plot(
    x_axis,
    svr.predict(x_axis),
    color='tab:purple', lw=10, alpha=0.35, label='SVR'
)

plt.gcf().legend()
```